# Import error of a Component File in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, button, import

I am pretty new to React Framework, What I am trying to do is that from my Dishdetail.js I am calling the `<Commentform />` component so that it displays me a button `Submit Comment` button. `Dishdetail.js` is completely fine so I submitted only part of my code from `Dishdetail.js` so that it doesn't look cluttered. The problem is for my `CommentformComponent.js` file component I am getting import errors saying

`./src/Components/DishdetailComponent.jsAttempted import error: 'Commentform' is not exported from './CommentformComponent'.`

I did write my export from my `CommentforComponent.js`
and here is my full code for `CommenforComponent.js` file

```
///THIS IS MY Dishdetail.js file
import {Commentform} from './CommentformComponent';

function RenderComments({comments}){  
        if(comments!=null){           
            const dishComments=comments.map( (comment) => { 
            return( 
                  <ul key={comment.id} className = "list-unstyled">
                 <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                 <p>--{comment.author},{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric',month: 'short', day: '2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))} </p>
                 </ul>
                  );

        return(
            <div>
                <h4>Comments</h4>
                {dishComments}
                <Commentform />
            </div>
        )
    }
        else{
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
        }
    }
```

```
///CommentformComponent.js file
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {  Button  } from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Control,LocalForm,Errors} from 'react-redux-form';

class Commentform extends Component{       
    render(){      
        return(

            <Button type="submit" color="outline-dark">
                <span className="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></span>Submit Comment
            </Button>
        );
    }

}
export default Commentform;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
import Commentform from './CommentformComponent';
```

Importing a component depends on how you export it:

```
export default Commentform;
import Commentform from './CommentformComponent';
```

or

```
export Commentform;
import { Commentform } from './CommentformComponent';
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked....But why did we omit the curly braces from Commentform?

Comment: If you export as `default`, no curly braces. You use curly braces when you export several components from the same file and without using default